# is it possible to read contact list directly from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to read a contact list without using intent or content provider, I mean directly communicate with SQLite.

Is there any way ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There are ways to add custom data to contacts.

Comment: faster way to read and write contact info(for real time system). can i over write it?tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for security reasons you will need to go through the content provider. Only the application (or, in this case, the Android OS) that owns the database is allowed to read it (unless it is stored in shared memory, which isn't the case for the default contacts database).

Comment: so is there any way that i can overwrite these classes(content provider) and make some changes and make it customize.